# MySQL Database Normalization .. one table to connect multiple others?

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

Let's assume I have a very large database with tons of tables in it.
Certain of these tables contain datasets to be connected to each other like

```
table: album 
table: artist
--> connected by table: album_artist

table: company
table: product
--> connected by table: company_product
```

The tables `album_artist` and `company_product` contain 3 columns representing primary key, albumID/artistID meanwhile companyID/productID...

Is it a good practice to do something like an "assoc" table which is made up like

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------
| id int(11) primary | leftID | assocType       | rightID |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| 1                  | 10     | company:product | 4       |
| 2                  | 6      | company:product | 5       |
| 3                  | 4      | album:artist    | 10      |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure if this is the way to go or if there's anything else than creating multiple connection tables?!

Comment: _And one ring to Rule Then All_

Comment: That sounds like a very very bad idea to me. What is the problem with creating specific connection tables?

Comment: You say "if this is the way to go", but there is no "this" except "something like this [example]. You haven't explained what "this" is, or what your example is an example *of*. Please explain as much as you can about what you think are trying to do and why you think you should do it. Also, you don't make clear what you mean by "creating multiple connection tables"--do you mean creating tables like "album_artist and company_product"? (Although, again, you don't clearly explain what those are.) Please *explain*, don't just use a few words that remind you of what you mean, but are not saying.

Comment: Read an introduction to relational information modeling. What is that table trying to accomplish? It is a union of (likely projections of) the obvious straightforward tables recording the situation. Don't group rows together because they have a similar pattern of FKs but because they state the same sort of thing about the situation by giving parameters for the same sentence template. (A FK just states that subrows somewhere appear elsewhere.) PS Why "3" PK columns? A pair of entities associated by a relationship (together, a CK (candidate key)) plus a surrogate (a 2nd CK)? Why the surrogate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no, a thousand times no. Don't overthink your many-to-many relationships. Just keep them simple. There's nothing to gain and a lot to lose by trying to consolidate all your relationships in a single table.

If you have a many to many relationship between, say `guiarist` and `drummer`, then you need a `guitarist_drummer` table with two columns in it: `guitarist_id` and `drummer_id`. That table's primary key should be comprised of both columns. And you should have another index that's made of the two columns in the opposite order.  Don't add a third column with an autoincrmenting id to those join tables. That's a waste, and it allows duplicated pairs in those tables, which is generally confusing.

People who took the RDBMS class in school will immediately recognize how these tables work. That's good, because it means you don't have to be the only programmer on this project for the rest of your life.

Pro tip:  Use the same column name everywhere.  Make your `guitarist` table contain a primary key called `guitarist_id` rather than `id`. It makes your relationship tables easier to understand. And, if you use a reverse engineering tool like Sql Developer that tool will have an easier time with your schema.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not a good practice.  It is a terrible practice, because referential integrity goes out the window.  Referential integrity is the guarantee provided by the RDBMS that a foreign key in one row refers to a valid row in another table.  In order for the database to be able to enforce referential integrity, each referring column must refer to one and only one referred column of one and only one referred table.

Comment: @philipxy I am afraid I do not understand what you are trying to say. Can you name any other places? How would you have rather worded the sentence?

Comment: I agree that for a given FK, "each referring column must refer to one and only one referred column of one and only one referred table". I mistook it as being about when some FK(s) should be declared for referencing columns.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it "depends" on the situation. In your case and most others, no, it does not make sense. It does make sense if you are doing a many <-> many relationship, the constraints can be enforced by the link table with foreign keys and a unique constraint. Probably the best use case would be if you had numerous tables pointing to a single table. Each table could have a link table with indexes on it. This would be beneficial if one of the tables is a large table, and you need to fetch the linked records separately.